# Converting nested JSON to CSV without hard coding column values

Tags: python, json, csv, export-to-csv

I am a rookie at Python and I have data files that I would like to convert from JSON to CSV. The issues are that my code returns an error I am unable to resolve and the data varies from file to file and I would like to have one script that can be applied to multiple files by just changing the file location. I would like to not hard code company name and company type but i don't know how to go about that. The data is structured as follows:

```
{
    "company_name": "Google",
    "company_type": "Public",
    "employees": [{
        "staff": [{
            "name": "John Doe",
            "type": "FTE",
            "id": "1111111111",
            "region": "Northeast"
        }, {
            "name": "Jane Doe",
            "type": "FTE",
            "id": "222222222",
            "region": "Northwest"
        }],
        "setup": [{
            "description": "Onsite",
            "location": "New York City"
        }, {
            "description": "Hybrid",
            "location": "Seattle"
        }],
        "role": [{
            "description": "Business Analyst",
            "salary": "70000"
        }, {
            "description": "Manager",
            "salary": "90000"
        }]
    }, {
        "contractors": [{
            "name": "Jessica Smith",
            "type": "PTE",
            "id": "333333333",
            "region": "Southeast"
        }],
        "setup": [{
            "description": "Remote",
            "location": "Miami"
        }],
        "role": [{
            "description": "Project Manager",
            "salary": "80000"
        }]
    }]
}
```

The code I have so far is:

```
import json
import csv
import ijson

file = open("C:/Users/User1/sample_file.json","w")
file_writer = csv.writer(file)
file_writer.writerow(("Company Name","Company Type","Name","Type","ID","Region","Description","Location","Description","Salary"))

with open("C:/Users/User1/sample_file.json","rb") as f:

  company_name = "Google"
  company_type = "Public"
  for record in ijson.items(f,"employees.item"):
    name = record['staff'][0]['name']
    type = record['staff'][0]['type']
    id = record['staff'][0]['id']
    region = record['staff'][0]['region']
    description = record['setup'][0]['description']
    location = record['setup'][0]['location']
    description = record['role'][0]['description']
    salary = record['role'][0]['salary']
    file_writer.writerow((comapny_name, company_type, name, type, id, region, description, location, description, salary))

file.close()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just need to loop through every layer looking for keys that match the column headers and place the data into a list based on the position of the column headers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of your files have the same general structure, using a `csv.DictWriter` should work.  Just iterate through the employee sections creating a single dictionary to represent each employee and call `writer.writerow()`  once all of the data has been collected.

For example:

```
import csv
import json


data = json.load(open(filename))
columns = ["company name","company type","name","type","id","region","description","location","salary"]

def convert(data, headers):
    with open("employees.csv", "wt") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=headers, extrasaction="ignore", restval=None)
        writer.writeheader()
        for emp_type in data["employees"]:
            lst = []
            for _, v in emp_type.items():
                for i,x in enumerate(v):
                    if len(lst) <= i:
                        lst.append({"company name": data["company_name"],
                                "company type": data["company_type"]})
                    lst[i].update(x)
            for item in lst:
                writer.writerow(item)

convert(data, columns)
```

OUTPUT

```
company name,company type,name,type,id,region,description,location,salary
Google,Public,John Doe,FTE,1111111111,Northeast,Business Analyst,New York City,70000
Google,Public,Jane Doe,FTE,222222222,Northwest,Manager,Seattle,90000
Google,Public,Jessica Smith,PTE,333333333,Southeast,Project Manager,Miami,80000
```